# Is Inferred List Initializes possible?

Tags: c#, .net

I know that i can initialize a collection as follows

```
var array = []{"1", "2", "3"};
```

which will automatically infer that i want to create an Array of type String, But this will restrict me from Adding or removing indexes from the array since an Array has a fixed size.

Is there anyway to do the same with the Generic List type and the the compiler should infer which type "T" is based on the items in the initializer?

Maybe something like new List(){...}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var list = new[] {"1", "2", "3"}.ToList();
```

Comment: read the question,  basically this is the simplest way for him to get what he wants.

Comment: Lol, having re-read the question I agree that you are correct Keith :).  He was just looking for a way to create List<string> without specifying type.  He really didn't need a generic whatsoever :)

Comment: +1 even though it's an ugly little duckling, I had to upvote this for being the most direct answer to the question...

Answer (score 4):

No, this is not supported - you have to specify the type parameter but can still use [collection initializers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb384062.aspx).

```
var list = new List<String> { "1", "2", "3" };
```

You could however create a helper method

```
public static class ListUtilities
{
    public static List<T> New<T>(params T[] items)
    {
        return new List<T>(items);
    }
}
```

and use it like this.

```
var list = ListUtilities.New("1", "2", "3");
```

But this is probably not worth it, you don't gain much if anything at all. And this will create an array first and use it to populate a list. So this is not that different from Keith Nicholas' `var list = new[] { "1", "2", "3" }.ToList();`.

Comment: +1 This is the same method used in `Tuple.Create`, which means instead of typing `new Tuple<String, int>("one", 1)`, you can just write `Tuple.Create("one", 1)`

Comment: Good hint - I was not aware of the `Tuple.Create()` methods and tried to avoid this classes especially because of the overly verbose constructor calls. Maybe this gives them a second chance.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a pretty nifty example:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var Customer = new { FirstName = "John", LastName = "Doe" };
    var customerList = MakeList(Customer);

    customerList.Add(new { FirstName = "Bill", LastName = "Smith" });
}

public static List<T> MakeList<T>(T itemOftype)
{
    List<T> newList = new List<T>();
    return newList;
}
```

http://kirillosenkov.blogspot.com/2008/01/how-to-create-generic-list-of-anonymous.html

Comment: Not a bad example. Using the type inference of a generic method to build a list. Nice.

Comment: Yeah, I was pretty stoked when I found it.  It's bookmarked as one of my "you should use this" pages :)

Comment: This is admittedly a clever trick to do things with anonymous types that seem impossible at first sight, but really don't use this. If you have to rely on type inference to get something working because you can not name the type this is a very good indication that your type should not be anonymous in the first place.

Comment: @DanielBrückner I was more being silly with my comment.  While it DOES do what the OP asked for, I'm never a huge fan of anonymous types when you could use a named type.  That said, I thought it was an interesting solution to the OP's question, hence why I posted it.  It Does solve the requirements of the question.

Comment: It is just coincidence that my comment sounds like an response to yours - I started typing it before you submitted yours but missed to submit mine for some time.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. But no inference .

```
var li = new List<int> {1,2,3,4,5,6};
```

Closest you will get is

```
var li = new List<dynamic> {1,2,3,4,5}
```

Comment: I think the OP is looking for type inference on the RHS of the expression.

Comment: this doesn't do type inference